# How does std::launder affect containers?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, c++17

Consider the following, simplified and incomplete, implementation of a fixed-sized vector:

```
template<typename T>
class Vec {
  T *start, *end;

public:
  T& operator[](ssize_t idx) { return start[idx]; }

  void pop() {
    end--;
    end->~T();
  }

  template<typename... U>
  void push(U... args) {
    new (end) T { std::forward<U>(args)... };
    end++;
  }
};
```

Now consider the following T:

```
struct T {
  const int i;
};
```

And the following use case:

```
Vec<T> v;
v.push(1);
std::cout << v[0].i;
v.pop();
v.push(2);
std::cout << v[0].i;
```

The index operator uses the `start` pointer to access the object. The object at that point was destroyed by `pop` and another object was created in its storage location by `push(2)`. If I read the documentation surrounding [std::launder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) correctly, this means that the behavior of `v[0]` in the line below is undefined.

---

How is std::launder supposed to be used to correct this code? Do we have to launder start and end each time placement new is used? Current implementations of the stdlib seem to be using code similar to the one posted above. Is the behavior of these implementations undefined?

Comment: `std::vector` hasn't been implementable in standard C++ since C++03.

Comment: @T.C.: Care to expand on that? Given that it, y'know, _is_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `data()`'s return value (or in C++03, `&v[0]`) is required to allow pointer arithmetic on it, and pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers into the same array. `vector`, for obvious reasons, can't actually use an array internally.

Comment: @T.C.: (Trying to confirm my understanding of what you're saying) Assuming you don't count a dynamically allocated "array" block as "an array", you also believe then that we cannot legally perform pointer arithmetic on, say, a `new int[N]`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `vector` *doesn't* `new` a `T[N]`. It allocates a block of storage and construct the elements one-by-one into that storage.

Comment: @T.C. `T` is `char` or something similar... At some point, there is a `new T[N]`, for some `T` (N.B. I'm not saying `T` is the vector element type)

Comment: @T.C.: Hmm are you invoking an aliasing problem then? I can't see any real problem here from 5.3.4/5 or 5.7/5 (C++14)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are not doing arithmetic on `char *`s unless you are actually having `vector<char>`. Perhaps I should have written "pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers that points to elements of the same array".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See also the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/p4BXNhTHY7U/ahp5CzNFQQAJ

Comment: @T.C. _"pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers that points to elements of the same array"_ Okay so that's what I thought you were saying, but I cannot see any standard wording to support this that requires the types to match (remember, `char*` happily aliases). I will read through the group discussion tomorrow but I get the feeling it's going to be far more pedantic than (a) I [impressive!] and (b) warranted... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126277/discussion-between-t-c-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: No, end points one byte beyond the last element.

Comment: Did you find an answer?? I am not sure in fact that you have an UB here.

Comment: I have not found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**How is `std::launder` supposed to be used to correct this code? Do we have to launder start and end each time placement new is used?**

From [P0532R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0532r0.pdf), you could avoid needing to call `launder()` if the return value of placement new is assigned to `end`. You would not need to change your start pointer unless the vector was empty since the object currently pointed to by `start` would still have an active lifetime with the code you provided.

The same paper indicates that `launder()` is a no-op unless the object lifetime has ended and has been replaced with a new object, so using `launder()` will not incur a performance penalty if it is unnecessary:

> [...] the type of `std::launder(this)` is equivalent to just this as Richard Smith pointed out: Remember that `launder(p)` is a no-op unless p points to an object whose lifetime has ended and where a new object has been created in the same storage.

**Current implementations of the stdlib seem to be using code similar to the one posted above. Is the behavior of these implementations undefined?**

Yes. [P0532R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0532r0.pdf) also discusses this issue and the content is similar to the discussion in the question's comments: `vector` does not use placement new directly, the return value of the placement new call is lost in the chain of function calls to the vector's allocator, and in any event placement new is used element by element so constructing the internal vector machinery cannot use the return value anyway. `launder()` appears to be the tool intended to be used here. However, the pointer type specified by the allocator is not required to be a raw pointer type at all and `launder()` only works for raw pointers. The current implementation is currently undefined for some types; `launder()` does not seem to be the appropriate machinery for solving the generic case for allocator based containers.