# Violation of const-correctness [placement new] and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, compiler-optimization, placement-new

I have read the following: [Placement new breaks consts and references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586848/placement-new-breaks-consts-and-references/7586946#7586946)
and by reading the slides from Matthis Kruse at the [C++ Meeting](https://meetingcpp.com/mcpp/slides/2018/prez.pdf) I am confused regarding  the following code

```
struct U { const int i; };
std::vector<U> B;
B.push_back({ 1 });
B.clear();
B.push_back({ 2 });
const int v = B[0].i; // <- Undefined Behavior
```

`B.clear()` only destructs the objects, and `B.push_back({2})` uses placement new to construct a new object at the start of the memory location `B` has allocated.

1. I don't understand quite why the access `B[0].i` is undefined behavior.
2. Could the compiler have cached `B[0].i` and possibly output `1`?
3. What has std::launder to do with all this? Is it a tool to really make sure these kind of compiler optimizations cannot happen?

The standard libcxx [llvm] implementation:

```
template <class Tp, class Allocator>
inline typename vector<Tp, Allocator>::reference
vector<Tp, Allocator>::operator[](size_type n)
{
   assert(n < size(), "vector[] index out of bounds");
    return this->__begin_[n];
}
```

is the same as in the slides.

References from std 2017:

- [8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.3) (Possible violation)
- [8.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.4) (mentioning std::launder)

Comment: This seems like a near duplicate of [How does std::launder affect containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40165022/364696).

Comment: My answer to [Implementing a std::vector like container without undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997191/1708801) may explain some of the details.

Comment: While launder was necessary in this example for c++17, it no longer is for c++20 due to changes in basic.lifetime. So the example is no longer UB.

Answer (score 1):

This example is no longer UB in c++20. That said, multiple push_backs will likely fail since the `U` copy assignment is deleted because it contains a const subobject. A copy assignment can be written using placement new which will allow normal operations with const subobjects w/o UB in c++20.

```
struct U { const int i; };
std::vector<U> B;
B.push_back({ 1 });
B.clear();
B.push_back({ 2 });
const int v = B[0].i; // <- No Longer Undefined Behavior in c++20

struct U { const int i; };
std::vector<U> B;
B.push_back({ 1 });
B.push_back({ 1 });  // likely to fail if the first push_back only reserves space for 1 entry (implementation dependent)
```