# Is it legal in c++ to construct array elements calling new in loop instead of new[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer, placement-new

I'm writing array wrapper in C++ (like `std::array`). The motivation was to make array-wrapper a derivative of interface. This enables to pass arrays to functions without making them templated (through interface). The way of implementing it is a little suspicious-looking so I want to ask if the code below is legal in C++ or not?
The example shows the way of using union members, I tried to make the smallest example so Interface and other stuff is not present here. Main problem is union member usage in that way. The reason I do so it to make possible to create array of types with no default c-tor (Unfortunately, this example doesn't show this too).

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Array
{
    public:

    Array() : 
        m_data( m_originalObjects ),
        m_len(N),
        m_place()
    {        
        for( decltype(N) i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            new( &m_data[i] )T();
        }
    }
        //c-tor to objects without default c-tor
        template<typename ... TCon>
        Array( TCon && ... values ) :
            m_data( m_originalObjects ),
            m_len(N),
            m_originalObjects{ static_cast<T>(values)... }
        {
        }

    private:

    T * m_data = nullptr;
    size_t m_len = 0;

    union
    {
        char m_place[sizeof(T) * N];
        T m_originalObjects[N];
    };
};
```

Comment: _"...array-wrapper a derivative of interface...."_ I don't see how you have achieved this.  Every instantiation of the `Array` template will be a different class.  Please show an example of the use of the template.

Comment: The problem here is accessing inactive union members. What's wrong with just having a plain `T[N]` member? Also, adding type erasure by rewriting all the basic library classes is possibly the wrong way to go. You can easily write a type erasure construct that wraps arbitrary template classes...

Comment: @RichardCritten It appears that the common (non-templated) base class is missing (because it's not really what the question is about).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - didn't want to guess would rather ask for clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is pointer arithmetic on inactive member of a union UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188737/is-pointer-arithmetic-on-inactive-member-of-a-union-ub)

Comment: Might be also relevant: [treating memory returned by operator new(sizeof(T) * N) as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53451770/580083). There are even discussions whether `std::vector` is implementable without UB, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52996590/580083) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40165022/580083).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - I dont use plain T[N] because I want be able to create arrays of elements without default c-tor. As a result I make something like what you recommended (type-erasure construct that wraps c-arrays). Sorry for incomplete information, I edit answer a bit

Comment: @RichardCritten It looks to me like this code has been simplified in order to ask the question without needing to talk about all the other parts of the code.

Comment: "*I dont use plain T[N] because I want be able to create arrays of elements without default c-tor*" But you are calling `T()` in the ctor of `Array`. So contrary to what you want to achieve, `Array`'s ctor won't compile if `T` doesn't have a default ctor.

Comment: Language Lawyer, thanks. Doing so is UB as I expect. Is there any way to activate proper member in union so that there will be no UB anymore?

Comment: @sebrockm add c-tor to this case in example code

Comment: Ok, but now, again, I don't see why you need the union at all and why a plain `T[N]` wouldn't suffice... if you have two ctors, one using `T()` and one using `T(TCon)` for initializing the elements of `m_originalObjects`, then at which place the union member `m_place` is needed at all?

Comment: @sebrockm, thanks, using simple T[N] work as I need to without using union and other dirty things

Comment: Answering the question in the title: not only using placement-new separately for each array element is correct, it's better than using placement-new for the entire array at once (because latter is allowed to insert arbitrary metadata at the beginning of the array, which is nonsense but notably is done by MSVC).

Comment: @sebrockm I don't think illustrating code has to show the usefulness of a construct in Q about whether a construct is well defined. Using raw storage gives obvious flexibility advantages, not limited to using a type that doesn't have a default ctor.

Comment: @curiousguy absolutely agreed. That's why I just mentioned it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @MaxLanghof For a few revision of the C++ std, neither active union member nor accessing a union member was defined. It's still a mess. What is `U.x` if `U` is a union instance and `x` not the active member? What is a lvalue? What is an object? C++ is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I expect that having c-style array of types without default c-tors as class member will fail compilation so I used union to "fix" this problem. The truth is that there is no such problem, thanks @sebrockm for opening my eyes on it. 
The following code is what I really needed

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Array
{
    public:

    Array() : 
        m_data( m_originalObjects ),
        m_len(N),
        m_originalObjects{}
    {        
    }

    //конструктор с параметрами
    template<typename ... TCon>
    Array( TCon && ... values ) :
        m_data( m_originalObjects ),
        m_len(N),
        m_originalObjects{ static_cast<T>(values)... }
    {
    }

    private:

    T * m_data = nullptr;
    size_t m_len = 0;

    T m_originalObjects[N];
};
```

Comment: What is the *point* of the `m_data` member? Have you considered how it behaves in the implicit copy constructor and assignment?

Comment: @eerorika, Actually m_data and m_len are members of base class, which is templated only by T. They are present in example to show the usage of union (in question example).

Comment: @ivanbubnikov This looks like all you want is something in between `std::array` and `std::vector`, i.e. something that implements run-time sizes but cannot be resized. A wrapper around `std::vector` would do that pretty easily. Or do you actually need the compile-time size for a different purpose?

Comment: @Max Langhof, I want to have something like StringView(base class to template array) to use fixed-size array to pass it to functions without need to make them template.

Comment: This is a typical XY problem.  You should have been asking something along the lines of "I want to have something like StringView(base class to template array) to use fixed-size array to pass it to functions without need to make them template" in the first place.

Comment: @L.F. sorry, my fault. When I asked about union I have no doubt that my way to implement StringView-like class was right. The only annoying thing was the union usage in such strange manner